# Как сделать ссылку на группу в контакте на странице профиля в разделе "Веб-сайт:"?

Tags: вконтакте, seo

такого вида конструкции не работают

```
@имягруппы(текст)

[имягруппы|текст]
```

Нужно, чтобы отображалось название группы, а не адрес